# Forward to different path in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm developing a login page for users, users with admin priviledge are forwarded to a specific path, and users with user privledge are forwarded to another path. I want to forward after processing the java class. I'm new to Struts 2.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Forward if you mean to redirect user to different page? if this is the case than all you have to set the result string in your action like

```
public class MyActionextends ActionSupport{
   String action="default"
   //getter and setter for action
    public String execute() throws Exception {
       String view;

        if admin
        view="admin_view"
        action="admin_view"
        if user
        view="user"
        action="user"
        return view;  


    }
]
```

in `struts.xml` do something like

```
<action name="myaction">
    <result name="user">user.jsp</result>
    <result name="admin_view">admin.jsp</result>
</action>

What dave has suggested
<action name="myaction">
    <result>/WEB-INF/${action}_home.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: more over for generic one you can go for what dave has suggested

Comment: FWIW you probably wouldn't want to redirect to a plain JSP as in your first result configuration, but rather forward, or redirect to an action.

Comment: Thank you guys DaveNewton and @umesh-awasthi

Comment: @DaveNewton when I forwarded to an action ${action} I get error: HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action com.savvytek.Login and result dxp

Comment: show action class snap shot and config file where you have configured it,without that will be hard to tell.It says there is no result defined means you have not telling framewoek what to do when this result is coming

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to just declare a different result for each user type.

```
<action name="login">
    <result name="admin">/WEB-INF/admin_home.jsp</result>
    <result name="user">/WEB-INF/user_home.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

An `actionRedirect` is likely more desirable, implementing the post-redirect-get pattern.

There are a few other options, including using an action variable to decide which to go to. For example, if you exposed an action property `which`:

```
<action name="login">
    <result>/WEB-INF/${which}_home.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```